# SQL: (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

i speak dutch, sorry for possible mistakes.
I trie to upload my database again via Bigdumper, but i get this error:

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `t5s10_osmap_sitemap_menus` (
    `sitemap_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `menutype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `changefreq` enum('always','hourly','daily','weekly','monthly','yearly','never') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'weekly',
    `priority` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.5',
    `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`sitemap_id`,`menutype_id`),
    KEY `idx_ordering` (`sitemap_id`,`ordering`),
    KEY `idx_sitemap_menus` (`sitemap_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_sitemaps_menus` FOREIGN KEY (`sitemap_id`) REFERENCES `t5s10_osmap_sitemaps` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL:

> Can't create table `nadine_united`.`t5s10_osmap_sitemap_menus` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Greetings, Nadine

Comment: Are `t5s10_osmap_sitemaps.id` and `t5s10_osmap_sitemap_menus.sitemap_id` the **exact** same type, length, not-null, unsigned, collation, etc.?

Comment: sorry, dont understand what you mean. Where can i find that? i'm new in sql.

Comment: Please add table definition for `t5s10_osmap_sitemaps` and read Conditions and Restrictions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: do you mean here?: `t5s10_osmap_sitemaps` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `params` text,
  `is_default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `links_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `default_idx` (`is_default`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

Comment: As long as t5s10_osmap_sitemaps is created first then there is no problem with the code.

Comment: no clue, it' s a longer existing website. Still don't ow what to do... But thanx!

Comment: @NadinePeeters what if you checked the answers to the duplucate topic, particularly the one highlighting how to coax more details out of mysql regarding the error!